# php session variable value is null when hosted to server

Tags: php, session, session-variables, shared-hosting

i having a strange issue in sessions.. this is working in WAMP server in my local machine.. my problem is wen hosted to a server in US it's not working..

im doing like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'testing login..';
```

in another page i'm doing:

```
session_start();
echo('my session value is : '.$_SESSION['test']);
```

but i'm getting only
my session value is :

my session value is not setting..

i checked the session.save_path in cPanel of the server it says /tmp.

pls help..
thanks in advance.

Comment: @sixeightzero I've always found that they do. Oh wait, you were asking OP if *his* cookies work...

Comment: Maybe the script closes to fast? (Depending on what happens after your set the variables). Try session_write_close() after you have set the variables.

Comment: where do you exactly doing session_start()?

Comment: @Rafael i put session_start(); in the beginning of the file.

Comment: It could be that the session files aren't getting written to the filesystem (not enough free space, permissions issue, etc.).  It could be that something else is deleting your sessions shortly after they're created.  Did you verify (using Firebug or something) that the PHPSESSID on your page that sets the `$_SESSION['test']` variable is the same as the one on the page you try to retrieve the variable?

Comment: @Noik  i tried session_write_close(); now.. but same problem. :(

Comment: @Rifky If you happen to have PHP 5.4 you can try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: @noik.. no the version is 5.3.13

Comment: is it something to do with time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your script dies because `session_start` fails with "headers already sent" ? This could happen, for example, if your test machine and production server don't encode new lines the same way...

The errors are probably not displayed on your production server, try something like that :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
```

and see if you get something useful.

Comment: make sure you are not naming your session variables starting with numbers (lime ```$_SESSION['1ABC']```) in Linux servers

Answer (score 1):

The php opening tag must be written at first line of a php file. This method help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a comment on another post.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on your `session.save_path`. This location will need to be writable by the Apache/httpd user.

Also check to see if you `session.save_path` contains any `sess_` prefixed files.

Comment: How to check the permission. I'm bit new to this.

Comment: Do you have command line access to the box? do `ls -la /tmp` Additionally, if your user is `chrooted`, `/tmp` may not be the file your session handler is looking for. You can always try a new path like `~/sessions`. Make the directory, update the ini or script, retry.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check that in the morning as I'm out of office now.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help.

my issue was security permission in /tmp folder. once it rectified it's working.

mean time dont use only numeric for SESSION ids, (Eg. $_SESSION['12345']) because in linux hosting its not taking the numeric only index and skipping that. (so use $_SESSION['ACS12345'])..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the way you created the file.

If you used auto language detection features, or something similar to create your file, then try creating a new PHP file. Copy your code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using siteground as your hosting you will need to enable the auto session. follow this steps

1. Navigate to Dev
2. click on php manager
3. click on php variables
4. Load more until you find session.auto_start
5. Turn it to yes and you're good to go